# Can't prevent my computer from falling asleep

Tags: release-juno

So ever since I've upgraded my Plex server to Juno yesterday, I can't prevent my machine from sleeping anymore. I've already set the the appropriate value in System Settings to never suspend, but it just keeps falling asleep after 15 minutes if I'm not logged in or after 30 minutes if I'm logged in.

This is really frustrating, as it was working as expected in Loki. Do I need to make further changes or is this a bug?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I think the inactivity used is the one last set before you switch to 'Never'